# Access web server running on Virtual box ubuntu on host windows machine

Tags: python, flask, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu using Virtual Box Manager from windows machine. Inside the VM box ubuntu i'm running a python flask application which is running at http://localhost:5000.

I tried to access the VM box localhost URL on windows machine using the VM box IP which I got using `ifconfig`. But it's says :

```
Your Internet access is blocked
```

Am i accessing it the right way ?

here is my python flask code :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: did you set the host in flask application ?

Comment: @HassanMehmood updated my python flask code

Comment: you need to give a host like this app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: ok that worked . thanks :)

Comment: so where was this running by default ? @HassanMehmood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a host='0.0.0.0' while starting your app. By default it will only accept requests from localhost. So if you are sending a request from some other IP then you must have to specify a host.

See below example.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Also if you want to activate the debugging mode to analyse the exceptions/errors while you access your application. You can also set debug attribute to 'True'.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, but what does host='0.0.0.0' actually mean?

Comment: @Echelon This means that your server is now accessible from any IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will allow you to access Flask web from any public IP instead of 127.0.0.1

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug='TRUE')
```

By default Flask runs on port: 5000. Sometime on VM this port will be blocked. To allow traffic on this port execute below command.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```